# Folder Access for multiple domains

Tags: web-server

I have two websites hosted on one server. The rootpath is:

1. /public_html
2. /public_html/2ndsite

I have uploaded the files of 2nd site to /public_html/2ndsite. It is working.

Now, I have a images folder(thousands of images) at public_html/images. I want to make this folder available at /public_html/2ndsite. I have tried "../images/image.gif", but doesn't work.

Whenever a image is inserted in first site, I would like to have that inserted in 2nd site also. Can I access the 1st site images in 2nd site withut using the URL (like www.site.com/images) as the image url shuld be "../images/image.gif" (images are inserted in 2nd site also, so in database I am storing this format.)

Comment: Please add a tag saying what web server you mean - it looks like Apache, but you'll need to explicitly say this before you get meaningful responses.  Also edit your message title to say it too.

Comment: How are you using these images? with a server side executable (PHP, ASP, Python, Rails, etc.) or with a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to attempt to interpret your question from your stream of consciousness:

"I have two websites hosted on one server. I want them to have separate content directories except for `/images` which should be shared between the two domains."

What you should do is:

1. Put the content for `site1.domain.com` into `.../public_html/site1.domain.com`
2. Put the content for `site2.domain.com` into `.../public_html/site2.domain.com`
3. Put the images into `.../public_html/common_images`

Then, create a symlink from `.../public_html/site1.domain.com/images` and `.../public_html/site1.domain.com/images` to `.../public_html/common_images`.

Now, whenever you access `http://siteX.domain.com/images`, you'll be served content out of the `.../public_html/common_images` directory.

Make sure that you tell your webserver to allow symlinks and content to be served from `.../public_html/common_images`.